# WPF. Необходимо чтобы текст Checkbox отображался слева и чтобы при наведении на него мышей чекбокс подсвечивался

Tags: wpf

Есть приложение написаное на WPF. Мне необходимо в формочке сделать Checkbox таким образом, чтобы сначала отображался текст чекбокса, а потом сам чекбокс. При этом необходимо чтобы при наведении мыши на текст чекбокс подсвечивался точно так же, как если бы мышу навели на него самого. И при клике чтобы он менял свое состояние на противоположное, но с этим как раз проблем никаких нет. В общем-то поведение необходимо точно такое же, как это и работает в чекбоксе, но в этом случае текст отображается справа, а мне необходимо слева. Пробовал использовать Label, примерно вот так:

```xaml
<Label Content="Test:" Target="{Binding ElementName=FlagTest}" />
<CheckBox x:Name="FlagTest" />
```

но так ничего при наведение на текст мыши не происходит. Пробовал еще обрабатывать соответствующие события текстового элемента с нужным текстом слева от чекбокса и вызывать события чекбокса, как-то вот так:

```xaml
private void TextTest_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    => FlagTest.RaiseEvent(new MouseEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0) { RoutedEvent = CheckBox.MouseMoveEvent });

private void TextTest_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    => FlagTest.RaiseEvent(new MouseEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0) { RoutedEvent = CheckBox.MouseLeaveEvent });

private void TextTest_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    => FlagTest.RaiseEvent(new MouseEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0) { RoutedEvent = CheckBox.ClickEvent });
```

но и так тоже не срабатывает — события генерируются, но эффекты чекбокса отсутствуют.

Как лучше и правильно такое сделать?

Спасибо!

Comment: Вы не в том направлении двигаетесь, ибо `Label` это ведь не часть чекбокса, да и C# тут не нужен, чисто XAML, чисто переопределение стилей.

Comment: Можно поконкретнее?

Comment: Пишете в XAML `<CheckBox Content="Чекбокс"/>`, простой, без стилей, без сторонних компонентов, и чего-либо еще. Жмете в дизайнере по нему `ПКМ` -> `Правка шаблона` -> `Правка копии...`, в открывшемся окне придумываем название стиля и указываем куда он будет размещаться, жмем ОК. Вам студия скопирует стандартный стиль элемента (его можете также узнать в [документации](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/checkbox-styles-and-templates)). Имея шаблон, ищем что хотите поменять и меняете местами. За квадрат отвечает `checkBoxBorder`, а за текст `contentPresenter`.

Comment: Подсветка при наведении на текст и так есть стандартно, но если хотите что-либо еще "подсветить", то внимание на `<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">` - знакомьтесь, это триггеры, которые делают что-то (запускают анимацию, меняют свойство стиля и т.д.) на основе чего-то (событие, привязанное свойство и так далее). Вот пишите там свой `Setter`, который сделает то, что вам надо.

Comment: Я в курсе как работают триггеры и что можно править шаблоны элементов. Но про то что можно попробовать изменить шаблон чекбокса — это как-то в голову не пришло. Спасибо за идею! Буду сегодня пробовать. Но если у меня в шаблоне получиться сделать так, чтобы контент отображался слева, а не справа, то триггеры трогать наверное уже и не нужно будет, так как при наведении курсора мыши на контент чекбокс подсвечивается в стандаотной компоновке, достаточно просто сделать так, чтобы контент отображался слева, а не справа.

Comment: Вот для чего это нужно и как должно выглядеть — чекбокс "З урахуванням регістру":

https://i.ibb.co/9ZMqSLx/src.png

Comment: Так, а зачем вы мне это тут уже 3-й раз пишете?) У вас не получилось или что?

Comment: Получилось! При том в шаблоне изменил только Grid.Column у ContentPresenter и у Border, который представляет сам чекбокс — поменял их местами. Больше ничего изменять не пришлось. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Вот результат: https://i.ibb.co/kSDgFw8/list.png